# How do we make Launcher/Home android app for AndroidTV device?

Tags: android-tv, android-launcher, app-launcher, android-device-manager

I did in Manifest.xml file

```
<!--    Start For Android Tv Box-->
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.live_tv"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
<!--    End For Android Tv Box-->
```

MainActivity is my first activity which is the firest screen of my app.

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
        android:stateNotNeeded="true"
        android:launchMode="singleInstance"
        android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"
        android:resumeWhilePausing="true"
        android:resizeableActivity="true"
        tools:targetApi="n">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />     
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />      
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data android:name="supports_leanback" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
```

When user tapped on Home button of AndroidTv remote Home/Launcher popup should come up and choose a launcher app for AndroidTv device, then whenever user power on device my app should be come as a launcher app.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Making an app as the launcher in Android TV is the same as other android devices. You only need to add a category named `android.intent.category.HOME` in your activiy's intent-filter. Use the following lines to change your `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        ...>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />
            ...
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: I have the same issue and did not work.

Comment: Hi @Mr_vmh, I didn't find a proper solution but I had made a mechanism, which is my application will be launch after boot android device.